# why my all url been proxy after setted apache reserve proxy?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, proxy, reverse

Background:
Now i have a java web project(in tomcat) and a php project(in apache).
I need to set a second domain in apache in order to proxy forward to tomcat.

Problem:
After I setted apache reserve proxy ,all url all be proxy to the tomcat.It is not expected;

config of reverse proxy in apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.captcha.zswlib.com
ServerAlias captcha.zswlib.com
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/captcha/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/captcha/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is not expected?

Comment: like zswlib.com also forward to //127.0.0.1:8080/captcha/.
all of  url be proxy to //127.0.0.1:8080/captcha/.